# How can I split a string and put it into a C# List in WebMatrix?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmatrix

I have seen many examples suggesting how to do this, however none of them work for me. I am not sure if it is because I am in WebMatrix or what, but all I want to do is split a string on the "\n" line break (no, not "\n\r", as I have put the \n's there myself). Here are the things I've tried/problems I am having:

Here:  http://www.dotnetperls.com/split  I can't use .split because "\n" is more than one 'char' and a little bit further below in that link, it suggests that I could use Regex.Split, however, that method doesn't seem to exist in my environment.

All other examples use "split" which will only see a single character.

What am I overlooking given these variables?:

```
var agendaLines = Request.Unvalidated("agendas");
List<String> saveLineList = new List<String>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an override for string.Split which allows for string, but you don't need it.  '\n' is a single character, as the "\" is an escape character.  So

```
List<String> saveLineList = agendaLines.Split('\n').ToList();
```

should work for you.  You may need to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

to the top of your code file, however.

Comment: In WebMatrix, you need not use "using System.Linq" for anyone's future benefit. This worked, but now, I have to figure out why my end result has too many line breaks in it, but that's probably a separate question. There may be some \r's left behind at some point. Thanks, everyone for the help!

Comment: This question was already answered but, yeah I just stripped out the 'supposed-to-be-robust' inclusion of "\r" with .Replace, and replaced with nothing, leaving only the "\n"s.

Comment: So if I used `List<String> saveLineList = agendaLines.Split("stringText").ToList();` that would work because of string.Split's override?

Comment: That specifically, no.  You would use the string override like this: List<String> saveLineList = agendaLines.Split(new string[] { "stringText" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList(); which I think we can all agree is rather clumsy, but for various good reasons is the best the CLR people could come up with.

Comment: Ok, well thanks for showing me that! It's better than nothing :)

Answer (score 1):

This works fine

```
var saveLineList = agendaLines.Split('\n').ToList();
```

Or if you want to ignore `"\n\n"`

```
var saveLineList = agendaLines.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```

This works because in reality, the `'\n'` is only a single character.